# GCC's reordering of read/write instructions

Tags: memory, gcc, linux-kernel, cpu, compiler-optimization

Linux's synchronization primitives (spinlock, mutex, RCUs) use memory barrier instructions to force the memory access instructions from getting re-ordered. And this reordering can be done either by the CPU itself or by the compiler.

Can someone show some examples of GCC produced code where such reordering is done ? I am interested mainly in x86. The reason I am asking this is to understand how GCC decides what instructions can be reordered. Different x86 mirco architectures (for ex: sandy bridge vs ivy bridge) use different cache architecture. Hence I am wondering how GCC does effective reordering that helps in the execution performance irrespective of the cache architecture. Some example C code and reordered GCC generated code would be very useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The reordering that GCC may do is unrelated to the reordering an (x86) CPU may do.

Let's start off with **compiler reordering**. The C language rules are such that GCC is forbidden from reordering `volatile` loads and store memory accesses with respect to each other, or deleting them, *when a sequence point occurs between them* (Thanks to [bobc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32536664/2809095) for this clarification). That is to say, in the assembly output, those memory accesses will appear, and will be sequenced precisely in the order you specified. Non-`volatile` accesses, on the other hand, can be reordered with respect to all other accesses, `volatile` or not, provided that (by the as-if rule) the end result of the calculation is the same.

For instance, a non-`volatile` load in the C code could be done as many times as the code says, but in a different order (e.g. If the compiler feels it's more convenient to do it earlier or later when more registers are available). It could be done fewer times than the code says (e.g. If a copy of the value happened to still be available in a register in the middle of a large expression). Or it could even be deleted (e.g. if the compiler can prove the uselessness of the load, or if it moved a variable entirely into a register).

To prevent compiler reorderings at other times, you must use a compiler-specific barrier. GCC uses `__asm__ __volatile__("":::"memory");` for this purpose.

This is different from **CPU reordering**, a.k.a. the **memory-ordering model**. Ancient CPUs executed instructions precisely in the order they appeared in the program; This is called *program ordering*, or the *strong memory-ordering model*. Modern CPUs, however, sometimes resort to "cheats" to run faster, by *weakening* a little the memory model.

The way x86 CPUs weaken the memory model is documented in Intel's Software Developer Manuals, Volume 3, Chapter 8, Section 8.2.2 *"Memory Ordering in P6 and More Recent Processor Families"*. This is, in part, what it reads:

- Reads are not reordered with other reads.
- Writes are not reordered with older reads.
- Writes to memory are not reordered with other writes, with [some] exceptions.
- Reads may be reordered with older writes to different locations but not with older writes to the same location.
- Reads or writes cannot be reordered with I/O instructions, locked instructions, or serializing instructions.
- Reads cannot pass earlier LFENCE and MFENCE instructions.
- Writes cannot pass earlier LFENCE, SFENCE, and MFENCE instructions.
- LFENCE instructions cannot pass earlier reads.
- SFENCE instructions cannot pass earlier writes.
- MFENCE instructions cannot pass earlier reads or writes.

It also gives very good examples of what can and cannot be reordered, in Section 8.2.3 *"Examples Illustrating the Memory-Ordering Principles"*.

As you can see, one uses FENCE instructions to prevent an x86 CPU from reordering memory accesses inappropriately.

Lastly, you may be interested in [this](http://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/) link, which goes into further detail and comes with the assembly examples you crave.

Comment: By the way, in-order execution is not sufficient to guarantee program order; it takes time for cache coherence information to be communicated and writes can be buffered on a cache miss. If [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_model_%28programming%29) is correct, C did not have a memory model standard until C11 (i.e., rather recently). Also, nice linked reference.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton AFAIK cache coherence is synchronous, precise, 100% reliable; it never gets any piece of info too late. Caches don't miss the train, they block the trains until they get on.

Comment: @curiousguy *Consistency* (across different addresses) is different from coherence (same address). Even a modestly relaxed memory consistency model like total store order allows visibility orders not allowed by sequential consistency.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton Yes but what role if any is played by 1) "time for cache coherence information to be communicated" 2) "writes can be buffered on a cache miss"? If you doing buffered writes, would removing the cache completely (in the abstract) restore memory consistency?

Answer (score 5):

- The C language rules are such that GCC is forbidden from reordering volatile loads and store memory accesses with respect to each other, or deleting them.

That is not true, and is quite misleading. The C spec **does not** make such guarantee.
See [When is a Volatile Object Accessed?](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Volatiles.html)

> The standard encourages compilers to refrain from optimizations concerning accesses to volatile objects, but leaves it implementation defined as to what constitutes a volatile access. The minimum requirement is that at a sequence point all previous accesses to volatile objects have stabilized and no subsequent accesses have occurred. Thus an implementation is free to reorder and combine volatile accesses that occur between sequence points, but cannot do so for accesses across a sequence point.

Traditionally, programmers have relied on volatile as a cheap synchronization method but this is no longer a reliable method.

Comment: `volatile` has special meaning on MSVC, going beyond what the C standard says (and what other compilers give it).  As I understand it, MSVC++ `volatile` is more like `std::atomic`, and even gets memory barriers.

Comment: I realize I've inadequately described the reordering guarantees that C makes. I should have said that if they are sequenced w.r.t. each other, that order will be reflected in the assembly exactly as given in the source code.