# Compare-And-Swap not working on many Cores

Tags: multithreading, gcc, concurrency, cpu, compare-and-swap

When I discovered the "CAS" instruction, I remember that I well understood that it could work for threads running on one single CPU but I was surprised that it could for many CPUs

Yesterday, I had my first opportunity to test it on one of my developments. I implemented it and it really worked fine; all my unit-tests was green. Perfect.

But today, I ran my unit-tests on another machine and they are now failing. Less perfect

The main difference on the two machines is that the first one (the one on which the unit-tests are green) is a quit old laptop, with only one core! The second one is more recent i7, and more powerfull...

Now, on my i7, if I force my unit-tests to run on one single core, they become successful. I do this by running

```
taskset -c <cpu-id> my-unit-test
```

Legitimately, my original question comes back: is CAS working on many cores? OK, according to what I read, I would be surprised if it didn't...

So what? I hope it comes from a bug in my code. To give you more information, I have a class with a critical section. I added an attribute

```
bool m_isBeingModified;
```

It is initialized to `false`. Moreover, at the beginning of my critical section, I run the function

```
inline void waitForClassBeingModified()
{
  while (!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&m_isBeingModified, false, true))
  {} /// I concider that I can to such a loop as my critical section is very light/short
}
```

Finally, at the end of my critical section, I reset my boolean variable

```
 m_isBeingModified = false;
```

I tried to set my attribute as `volatile` but it did not change anything: my unit-tests are still failing

Last information:

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) 6.2.0 20161005
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you rolling your own mutex as a learning experience or are you writing production code?  If the later, then you might want to reconsider using the synchronization objects that are provided in libraries (like pthread) or by the operating system.

Comment: My code is not for production. It is more a test in order to understand the usage of CAS via __sync_bool_compare_and_swap

Answer (score 2):

Also use `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` to unset the variable instead of just `m_isBeingModified = false;`. Also, don't implement your own mutex...

Both the compiler and the CPU can reorder code in unintended ways. The `__sync` primitives are marked in such a way to prevent this reordering from happining. Thus, with `m_isBeingModified = false;` it could very well the case that the compiler would first set the variable to `false` and only then generate the code for whatever you intended to be inside of the critical region.

Comment: Thank you. I am very surprised by the reordering as it also occurs if I declare my attribute as being `volatile`.
However, it seems that you are right: if I also use `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` to unset my variable, my problem disappears.

Comment: What do you mean by "Also, don't implement your own mutex"? Do you mean that I should use the "standard" pthread mutexes or do you have another thing in mind?

Comment: Yes, I mean that you should just use the "standard" pthread mutexes.

Comment: `volatile` has only a meaning to the compiler. The CPU does not see it at all, so it is still allowed to reorder memory access around this store. Also, `volatile` doesn't have much meaning in the C standard. I don't really know about a situation where it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Uli's precious help, I think that I have now all the elements to answer to my question.

*First of all, I may not be clear until there but the function I want to protect against concurrent access is very light. It takes around 80 cpu cycles to complete ([TSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter)). That's why I prefer to implement my own 'light' concurrent mutex based one CAS than using `pthread_mutex`.*

I found [this interesting page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106843/gccs-reordering-of-read-write-instructions) that explains how to 'temporarily' disable the code-reordering thanks to the following instruction:

```
__asm__ __volatile__("":::"memory");
```

Using it, I really boost my concurrency-protection and, of course all my tests are still successful.

To get a summary, the following list reports the impact on performance of different solutions I tried:

- **Original code (without protection)**: around 80 TSC
- **Double CAS (set & unset variable)**: around 105 TSC
- **Mutexes based solution**: around 120 TSC
- **Single CAS + disable reordering**: around 85 TSC